# Jquery loading image while image is loading

Tags: jquery

I made the following script to show a loader while a image is loading, my only question is how to implant this on multiple image's ?

working script: http://jsfiddle.net/4QhjD/

the jQuery part

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $("#image").load(function(){
        $("#waiter").fadeOut(function(){
            $("#image").fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

the html

```
     <div id="content">
       <div id="waiter"><img src="http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/page-loader.gif"></div>
       <img src="http://responsiveslides.com/1.jpg?PREVENT_CACHE=6200" id="image"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: @imjared Why? In this context it's being used in the same way the `.click()` or `.mouseup()` function might be used. Read the manual, please

Comment: @Bojangles whoa, learn something new every day. Didn't know that. Manual = read. Thanks for heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use class instead of id's like.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="waiter">
        <img src="http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/page-loader.gif">
    </div>
    <img src="http://responsiveslides.com/1.jpg?PREVENT_CACHE=6200" class="image" />
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="waiter">
        <img src="http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/page-loader.gif">
    </div>
    <img src="http://responsiveslides.com/2.jpg?PREVENT_CACHE=6200" class="image" />
</div>
```

Code:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $(".image").load(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".waiter").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).siblings(".image").fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/kk7ad/

Answer (score 0):

You are using an id `#image` meaning you can only use your script 1 time ( the same id can oly be use 1 per page ), you should try to use a `class="image"`, then you can doit like so.

`$('.image').each(function (){
  //Your code goes here.
})`